# InvalidArgumentError: slice index 7 of dimension 1 out of bounds. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/

Tags: python, tensorflow

Getting the Error while executing the below code: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:108 : Invalid argument: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims

```
 def random_actions(self,cur_state):
        s=[]
        dest=9
        states=self.get_state(cur_state)
        for index, tuple in enumerate(states):
            actions=tuple[0]
            weights=tuple[1]
            s.append(actions)
            actions=list(s) 
        return actions

num_hidden = 2
num_actions =env.random_actions(3)
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(2))
common = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")(inputs)
action = layers.Dense(len(num_actions), activation="softmax")(common)
critic = layers.Dense(1)(common)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[action, critic])

state = env.reset()
state=list(state)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    for timestep in range(1, max_steps_per_episode):
        state = tf.convert_to_tensor(state,np.float32)
        action_probs, critic_value = model(state)
        critic_value_history.append(critic_value[0, 0])
        action = np.random.choice(num_actions, p=np.squeeze(action_probs[0]))
        action_probs_history.append(tf.math.log(action_probs[0, action]))
        state, next_state,reward, = env.step(action)
        rewards_history.append(reward)
        steps.append(action)
```

**Error:**

While processing the below Line :

```
    action_probs_history.append(tf.math.log(action_probs[0, action]))

InvalidArgumentError: slice index 7 of dimension 1 out of bounds. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/
```

> 2020-11-23 06:09:03.890424: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at
> strided_slice_op.cc:108 : Invalid argument: Index out of range using
> input dim 1; input has only 1 dims

**Need Suggestion.**

Answer (score 0):

I think your redefined the name "action". You used it as your dense layer output and you used the same name later as output of your random.choice(). I do't know if this is the reason for the error, but it certainly does not look correct.